# Ensuring field alignment in struct

Tags: c, struct, alignment

I'm designing an abstract syntax tree (AST) for a language.  My lexical tokens look like

```c
typedef struct {
    tokenHeader header;
    tokenData data;
} lexicalToken;
```

where `tokenHeader` and `tokenData` are `struct`s.  As for my AST nodes, I have a base type:

```c
#define AST_HEADER \
    struct astNode *parent; \
    tokenHeader header;

typedef struct astNode {
    AST_HEADER
} astNode;
```

along with some splitting types.  E.g.,

```c
typedef struct {
    AST_HEADER
    astNode *nodes[2];
} astTwoSplitNode;
```

The reason why I don't include `tokenData` in `AST_HEADER` is because almost all tokens don't use that field.  This brings me to

```c
typedef struct {
    astNode *parent;
    lexicalToken token;
    // Nodes which use tokenData are always terminal nodes.
} astNodeWithData;
```

This finally brings me to my question: Is `astNodeWithData` guaranteed to be arranged in such a way that I can cast an `astNodeWithData*` to an `astNode*`, reference the `header` field, and access its fields in the expected way?

If not, is there a way to instruct my compiler (gcc, if it helps) to enforce such an arrangement?

Comment: "such a way that I can cast a astNodeWithData* to an astNode*, " is best avoided.  Look to a solution that does not involve a _cast_.  (`struct/union` of `struct`, etc.)

Comment: do not forget to pack structs even if you use unions or memcpy

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, why should this be avoided?  Isn't this what things like `struct sockaddr*` do?

Comment: `struct sockaddr*` is used in a controlled subset of C (e.g. *nix), not in the wide world of C.  Code can use the cast trick for the first member (if common type), but beyond that, portability is sacrificed and UB looms.  The cast trick also  defeats type checking. IMO, it is neither necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What you can actually do is cast a `astNodeWithData *` to a `astNode **`, not a  `astNode *`, as the address of a struct is the same as the address of the first member.

Section 6.7.2.1p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding "Structure and union specifiers" states:

> Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the
> units  in  which  bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in
> the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure
> object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial  member  (or
> if  that  member  is  a bit-field,  then  to  the  unit  in  which  it
> resides),  and  vice  versa.** There may  be  unnamed padding within a
> structure object, but not at its beginning

So the following would be allowed:

```
astNodeWithData dataNode;
// populate dataNode
astNode **nodePtr = (astNode **)&dataNode;
// access (*nodePtr)->header
astNodeWithData *dataNodePtr = (astNodeWithData *)nodePtr;
// access dataNodePtr->token
```

Comment: But would `dataNodePtr->token` be guaranteed be at the same offset as `(*nodePtr)->header`?

Comment: @DanielWalker They almost definitely would **not**.   The first member of `astNodeWithData` is `parent` i.e. a `astNode *`, so the `astNode` object is stored elsewhere.  The second member of `astNodeWithData` is `token`  i.e. a `lexicalToken` which 1) is distinct from the pointer `parent` and 2) does not appear to have anything in common with what `parent` points to.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I didn't phrase that question properly.  What I really want to know is if `offsetof(astNode, header)` is guaranteed to be equal to `offsetof(astNodeWithData, token)`.

Comment: @DanielWalker It depends on the types of `tokenHeader, lexicalToken`.

Comment: Gotcha.  So, it looks like a I could do `#define AST_HEADER struct { struct astNode *parent; lexicalHeader header;};` and then put an extra `lexicalData data;` in my `astNodeWithData`.